# Is it possible to pass #define flags to vcpkg packages for compiling?

Tags: c, package-managers, vcpkg

Is there a way to pass build #define flags to `vcpkg` packages? I'm using Manifest mode.

Specifically, I want to set the `_GLFW_WNDCLASSNAME` define when building the [glfw3](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/blob/master/src/win32_window.c#L1268) package via vcpkg.

This is the [portfile](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/ports/glfw3/portfile.cmake) for glfw3. I don't know the details of portfiles, but I don't see that #define being used in there.

Answer (score 0):

In the Cmake configuration in options you set the compiler flags. Add:

```
 -D_GLFW_WNDCLASSNAME=something
```

`-D` in GCC:

> `-D name`
>
> Predefine name as a macro, with definition 1.
>
> `-D name=definition`
>
> The contents of definition are tokenized and processed as if they appeared during translation phase three in a ‘#define’ directive. In
> particular, the definition is truncated by embedded newline
> characters.
>
> If you are invoking the preprocessor from a shell or shell-like program you may need to use the shell’s quoting syntax to protect
> characters such as spaces that have a meaning in the shell syntax.
>
> If you wish to define a function-like macro on the command line, write its argument list with surrounding parentheses before the equals
> sign (if any). Parentheses are meaningful to most shells, so you
> should quote the option. With sh and csh, `-D'name(args…)=definition'`
> works.
>
> `-D` and `-U` options are processed in the order they are given on the command line. All -imacros file and -include file options are
> processed after all `-D` and `-U` options.

Comment: The vcpkg tool downloads and builds the packages automatically, based on the definition of a vcpkg.json file. I'm not building those packages manually. My question is how to tell the vcpkg tool to compile those packages with the given #define value.

Comment: @Dess in **portfile**. You have cmake opinions there.

Comment: Oh, you're saying to change the portfile code in the vcpkg repo locally download. I'll give that a try. But, ideally, I'm looking for a way to pass compiler flags to the package without having to mess with the vcpkg repo files.